# Take screenshot of web page containing javascript from the command line

Tags: shell, webpage-screenshot

I have tried several screenshot tools, but have been unable to find one that supports taking a screenshot of

https://www.google.com.ph/maps/@55.6652884,12.4946009,89a,35y,254.22h,47.58t/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

The tricky part here is that the tool needs to support 3D, and wait until all tiles have been loaded in hi-res before taking the screenshot. It is probably very hard to determine that, so it is also acceptable that it simply takes the screenshot after giving the javascript 15 seconds to run.

Is there a beast that supports urls like the above?

The closest I have is:

```
cutycapt --delay 15000 --url='https://www.google.com.ph/maps/@55.6652884,12.4946009,89a,35y,254.22h,47.58t/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en' --out=google.png
```

which waits, but does not give the 3D.

Comment: selenium using java, selenium using robot framework, selenium using python there you can try

Comment: I suppose that problem here is not the load and render time (delay) but (lack of) WebGL support in headless engines. (I've tried screenshoteer [1] that uses Puppeteer but got plain aerial photo as well, though it seems on certain platforms this could work, probably.)
[1] https://github.com/vladocar/screenshoteer

Comment: @myf Do you have any idea, why the headless engines (including Firefox and Chromium) do not have WebGL? And how do you test for that?

Comment: (You test with: http://webglreport.com/?v=2 `cutycapt` support v1 but not v2).